# Multiple positioned-aligned classes pulled to one div instead of their individual div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/58arV/

I got 4 answers where one will be correct by the choosing of user in a "question-making" component.

So, I thought of doing it with 4 input styles and a DIV on the right of all 4 posing as a checkmark "radio"... so if the user clicks on box.. that box gets a "checkmark" while the rest get the red "x"...

```
<div class="answer">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="answer" id="answer-1" placeholder="Answer 1" class="form-control input" value="" />
<button type="radio" class="btn btn-success answer-type" style="" value="1">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
<div class="left-check"></div>
</button>
</div>
```

The problem is that all of the boxes are pulled to the top-right of the first input.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to is the following additional CSS:

```
.answer { position:relative; }
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/58arV/1/

As a rule of thumb (possibly as per CSS specification): An absolute element is positioned relative to it's closest parent that is either relative or absolute.

Comment: Wow, such an easy solution. Why did I not think of that... my brain just melts. Thank you.